# How can I use a search button using JavaScript Triple Combo Box?

Tags: javascript, combobox

I am using [this Cut & Paste Triple Combo script.](http://javascriptkit.com/script/script2/triplecombo.shtml).
This does not have a search button next to it. How can I put a search button instead of direct select URL linking?

Here is the double combo with Go button

But the triple does not have a search button. How can I put a search button in that Triple Combo Script?

Please provide all the code so I can just copy and paste, because I am not good with JavaScript programming.

Thank You. I will appreciate your help!

Comment: I wouldn't go with that script. It's an old way of using JavaScript. 
Instead of it use something else, I would suggest jQuery + some plugin, maybe this one http://plugins.jquery.com/project/chained-combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your third select box there is an `onchange` event calling a function `redirect2`. Remove that.

After your third select box, create a button by using `<input type="button" name="go" value="go">`. Add a event on it: `onclick=redirect2(document.getElementsByName('stage3')[0].options.selectedIndex);`

And you are good to go.

Comment: @Hooshkar: If @sushil's answer solved your question, please click the check mark next to his answer.